# <tr>-borders doesn't appear in outlook

Tags: html, css, outlook, border

I am having some trouble with my HTML tables in Outlook 2007+.
All borders on my `<tr>`-elements are not showing up!

During development, I use html-files and .css-files. I then use a tool to merge the two together.

when merged, Chrome opens the html-file like this:
[image: table working in chrome]

However, when I send the mail as an html-mail, Outlook displays it like this:
[image: table not working in outlook 2007+]

After merging, all my `<tr>`-elements look like this:

```
<tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #caecf0;"></td>
```

Do any of you know why?

---

Also, if anyone knows why the table footer is bigger than the header (they have the exact same styling) in outlook, please let me know ;-)

Comment: I have the same issue. It appears that Outlook ignores the border styling when applied to a <tr> tag. The same table renders as I would expect when rendered in Chrome, but has no borders when rendered in Outlook. Unfortunately I haven't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't apply a border to a table row. You should apply it to the table cell

```
<td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #caecf0;"></td>
```

It's impossible to say why your table row tags are being broken without seeing your html but I would guess that you haven't closed the tags properly or the tool you are using to inline your CSS is rubbish